# creating new column from existing columns instead of update

Tags: postgresql

I have data like this:

```
create table mytest (
staff_n int,
emp_name text
);

insert into mytest values (1,'James'),(1,'James H'),(2,'B Hua'),(2,'B Huatur');

1   "James"
1   "James H"
2   "B Hua"
2   "B Huatur"
```

The goal is to normalize the names with the ids, so as to have only the `max()` of the name for every id. I managed to update the column in place with this query.

```
with temp_t as (
select staff_n,max(emp_name) as max_emp from mytest
group by staff_n)
update mytest
set emp_name = max_emp
from temp_t
where mytest.staff_n = temp_t.staff_n;
```

Resulting in this data:

```
1   "James H"
1   "James H"
2   "B Huatur"
2   "B Huatur"
```

But I really would like to have an additional column , say `emp_name_normalized` and leave the one updated untouched.
Expected output is:

```
staff_n  emp_name   epm_name_normalized
1   "James"       "James H"
1   "James H"     "James H"
2   "B Hua"       "B Huatur"
2   "B Huatur"    "B Huatur"
```

Comment: Do you have something against `ALTER`ing the table to add a column and then running that same update query with `SET emp_name_normalized = ...` instead?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output

Comment: yes, I have a trigger on updates, I don't want update anything other than external logic that is input on my database. My internal logic should not get triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the column `emp_name_normalized` :

```
ALTER TABLE mytest
ADD COLUMN emp_name_normalized varchar(20);
```

Then use your query to fill `emp_name_normalized`  :

```
with temp_t as (
  select staff_n, max(emp_name) as max_emp from mytest
  group by staff_n
)
update mytest
set emp_name_normalized = max_emp
from temp_t
where mytest.staff_n = temp_t.staff_n;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/R0U3vJv-)